# How to change CVS username for a project that I imported

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, cvs

I imported a project from a colleague's workspace in eclipse. I made some modifications to the project and now I want to commit the changes to CVS. When I try to commit the changes, it has my colleague's username and asks for his password. It won't let me change the username to my username in the pop-up box.

Is there a way to change the username associated to CVS for an individual project in eclipse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just associate new repository (could be the same but with different credentials) with your project. More details:

http://blog.maestropublishing.com/2010/03/changing-cvs-username-and-password-in.html

Comment: Ahh yes there it is. I knew it was somewhere in the properties.