# How can I change my CVS user profile without proceeding from scratch

Tags: eclipse, cvs

So I am working with CVS under eclipse to synchronize updates with my team and I want to change CVS profile without setting up the environment from scratch. I only want to change the CVS user.

Comment: what is your CVS? what exactly u try to do? did u try to search in eclipse docs?

Comment: I want to create a new root so to assign all my projects without deleting and importing them? so the solution was to create a new repository then to change project user.

Answer (score 1):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6918186/535203) to [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6918092/535203) says:

> Just associate new repository (could be the same but with different credentials) with your project. More details:
>   http://blog.maestropublishing.com/2010/03/changing-cvs-username-and-password-in.html

I copy the content of this blog here in order not to loose the process (it worked for me).

---

1. **You need to set a new connection string for the CVS repository you want to access by using the CVS Repository view.**

*Goto the "Window" menu -> "Show View" -> "Other" -> find "CVS" section and expand -> "CVS Repositories"*

2. **Next setup the new connection string for your repository**

*Click on the mini icon of this view (a cylinder with the word "CVS" and a "+" sign) -> Add your new CVS repository*

3. **Associate the new repository (could be the same repository with different login credentials) with your project**

*Right click on the project in the "Navigator" -> select "Properties" -> in the properties tree select "CVS" -> hit the "Change Sharing..." button -> select your new repository and "OK" -> hit "Apply" back on the properties page*

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse, if you want to only change the CVS account you can do the following :

**1. Open the CVS Repository view**

Windows > Show view > Other > CVS/CVS Repositories

**2. Access the properties of the repository you want to update**

Right click > Properties

**3. Change the user/password**